# Vector<double> as class member variable

Tags: c++

Just like I'm creating member variables for `x`, `y`, and `theta`, how would I create member variables for the type `vector<double>` in the constructor? What I'm doing below doesn't seem to work.

```
Positioning::Positioning(double x, double y, double theta) {
    this->globalX = x;
    this->globalY = y;
    this->globalTheta = theta;
    
    vector<double> this->xs;
}
```

I have done `#include <vector>` and have `std::vector<double> xs;` in the private section of `Positioning.hpp`

**EDIT**

Header file:

```
namespace Position {
    class Positioning {
        private:
            double globalX;
            double globalY;
            double globalTheta;
            std::vector<double> xs;

        public:
            Positioning(double x, double y, double theta);
            ~Positioning();
            void updateGlobalPosition(double left_dist, double right_dist, double rear_dist);
            double getX();
            double getY();
            double getTheta();
    };
}
```

Comment: `vector<double> this->xs;` that's not how you define class member variables in c++. How does the `Positioning` class definition look like?

Comment: Thanks for your time, I have added the header file as an edit

Comment: So you're asking about how to **initialize** that vector class member? You should adapt your questions wording accordingly please.

Comment: Sorry about that. I am new to english so I apologize. I think people below helped me with my confusion. I thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works

```
Positioning::Positioning(double x, double y, double theta) {
    this->globalX = x;
    this->globalY = y;
    this->globalTheta = theta;
}
```

All your class variables are **created** automatically, you don't have to do anything special to create them.

The code in the body of the constructor above is not creating anything, it's **assigning** values to your variables. Of course if you want to give a member variable a particular value, then you have to do something, but they get created automatically.

Comment: Oh ok. So If I wanted to assign the variable `this->xs` the vector<double>, would I just do  `this->xs = xs`? Since xs is created in the private section of the class declaration.

Comment: Assumung `xs` is a variable of the correct type then that will work.

Comment: @itsMeMoriarty That assumes there's a variable called `xs` you want to copy in. If you add it as a fourth constructor parameter, sure. Or if you want it empty at the constructor, you don't need to do anything: it already exists, and is empty by default.